# Does Thread.currentThread() always return the same instance?

Tags: java, multithreading, dictionary

Can I make `ConcurrentHashMap<Thread, object>` to store a thread's data and use `Thread.currentThread()` to retreive it? I checked the Java source, and found that `currentThread()` is native and that `equals` is not overwritten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could, but there is a built in mechanism [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) for just that purpose.  The only reason to reinvent it is if you need to also access those values from some thread other than their "owner" in order to manipulate them.

```
  ThreadLocal<Object> data = new ThreadLocal<Object>();

  public Object getData() {
      return this.data.get();
  }

  public void setData(Object data) {
      this.data.set(data);
  }
```

Note that the initial value for every thread is null, but you can supply default values:

```
  ThreadLocal<Object> data = new ThreadLocal<Object>() {
      protected Object initialValue() { return "foo"; }
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you'll always get the same `Thread` object, so you can do this.

Rather than making such a table yourself, though, consider using the [`ThreadLocal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) capability, which is essentially doing the same thing, but with specific semantics for initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can but the problem with this approach is that you're creating a hard reference to the thread, which means that even when the thread is terminated, objects it references won't be collected by the GC.